# Storage of single/group of integer values

Tags: c#

am working on a bit unusual requirement wherein there is an integer parameter x, which can take a single value or a group of values. If the parameter takes a group of values, it is enough for me to store only the maximum and minimum. Usual C# thinking made me to to have four variables namely x, minX, maxX and boolean variable (to know whether the variable takes a single or group of values), I have four such parameters, which results in bloating of class variables (total 16 variables).

Is there any construct in C# which helps me in an efficient storage with the above constraint? I couldnt think beyond nullable values.

Comment: Is `minX` and `maxX` not enough? If they have the same value this it is not a range, if they are different then it is a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create your own [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

or look at [System.Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) - a built in generic 'container' class

Answer (score 0):

`min` and `max`.

If there's only one value, then `min` == `max`.

You can even offer some sugar to the caller for this case:

```
public SomeType MyMethod(int minA, int maxA, int minB, int maxB, int minC, int maxC, int minD, int maxD)
{
  //real work here.
}
public SomeType MyMethod(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
  return MyMethod(a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d);
}
```